# What does $1 ++ $0 mean in the closure for Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I was looking at the [code](https://github.com/careercup/CtCI-6th-Edition-Swift/blob/master/Ch%202.%20Linked%20Lists/Ch%202.%20Linked%20Lists.playground/Pages/2.1%20Remove%20Duplicates.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift) for how to remove duplicates from a list and I came upon some syntax I am unfamiliar with. What does $1 ++ $0 mean?

```
extension List where Element: Hashable {

    func removeDuplicates() -> List {
        var set = Set<Element>()
        let list = reduce(List()) {
            guard !set.contains($1) else { return $0 }
            set.insert($1)
            return $1 ++ $0
        }
        return list.reversed()
    }
}
```

Comment: `++` is a custom infix operator, defined in https://github.com/careercup/CtCI-6th-Edition-Swift/blob/master/Ch%202.%20Linked%20Lists/Ch%202.%20Linked%20Lists.playground/Sources/List.swift

Comment: BTW in Xcode you can command click on an operator, and jump to its definition.

Comment: Fun fact: this could be implemented with `var set = Set<Element>(); return set.insert($0).inserted ? $1 ++ $0 : $0`. Swift gives you a lot of syntactic rope to hang your users with, if you're not careful about keeping things eligible

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica in the storyboard I can't command click on the ++ to get to the definition.

Comment: This code is *in* the story board? How's that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$0` is the first parameter passed into the closure.

`$1` is the second parameter.

`++` is a custom infix operator

```
infix operator ++

private func ++<Element>(element: Element, list: ListNode<Element>) -> ListNode<Element> {
    return list.insert(element: element)
}
```

It will insert the element on the right to list on right of the operator